# how to count array which has the same attribute

Tags: php

I have an array like below. What I want is to echo a word according to number of `$my[]['title']` items. in this case the word must be repeated 4 times.
the sudo code is sth like this:

```
<?php
$my[0]['title']='first title';
$my[0]['description']='description';
$my[0]['date']='date';
$my[1]['title']='second title';
$my[1]['description']='description';
$my[1]['date']='date';
$my[2]['title']='third title';
$my[3]['title']='forth title';

for($i=0;$i<count($my[]['title'];$i++)
    echo 'this is test';
?>
```

Comment: `echo count(array_column($my, 'title'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test data would work fine with a `foreach` loop, but assuming that your array can contains rows that don't have a **title** key, you can use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
$count = count(array_column($my, 'title'));

for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
    echo 'this is test';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what `foreach` is for. It iterates over your entire array

```
foreach($my as $row) echo 'This is my test;
```

This echos whatever you want once per array entry

Comment: @ no I want to echo this word 4 times. because I have 4 `[]['title']`. is it clear

Comment: @johnjohn You want to echo the same word once per array entry?

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 0;
foreach($my as $val){
    if(isset($val['title'])){
        echo 'this is test';       
        $count++;
    }
}
```

Outputs "this is test" depending on how many times it see the `title` index.

Working code: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9c19bfac8fedb02a9840cdfb4f9217ccb110c7bc

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_column`:

```
$titleCount = count(array_column($my, 'title'));
for($i=0; $i<$titleCount; $i++)
    echo 'this is test';
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

As per the linked manual, this is available from php v5.5.

If you are using an older version (you should really update...) then here is the equivilent user defined function (from the manual comments section):

```
if(!function_exists("array_column"))
{

    function array_column($array,$column_name)
    {

        return array_map(function($element) use($column_name){return $element[$column_name];}, $array);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php5.5 and above, use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function to catch all the keys you want and then count them.

```
$my[0]['title']='first title';
$my[0]['description']='description';
$my[0]['date']='date';
$my[1]['title']='second title';
$my[1]['description']='description';
$my[1]['date']='date';
$my[2]['title']='third title';
$my[3]['title']='forth title';

$a = array_column($my, 'title');

if (count($a) >= 4) {
    # your code 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do use the `array_column` method (as many people have rightly recommended), you don't need to use a loop. You can use `str_repeat` instead.

```
 echo str_repeat('this is test', count(array_column($my, 'title')));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($my as $key => $val){
    if ( isset( $val['title']) ){
        echo $key;       
    }
}
```